# How to grant full permissions on an S3 bucket for an IAM user using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I am creating multiple IAM users dynamically with username as `username` and creating an S3 bucket with the `username-bucket` as name.

I want to grant full permissions for the newly created user on the s3 bucket that is created with `username-bucket` as name.

I have gone through `boto3` documentation where in they're assigning policies to an `s3` bucket. 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-bucket-policies.html

But it applies to any user. There is no option to pass an username which is supposed to have permissions on the bucket.

Is there any such option to do in `boto3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the `Principal` to `*` as in the example you linked, you would want to specify the user as the `Principal` using the format:

```
"Principal": {"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::account-number-without-hyphens:user/username"}
```

For more information on specifying a `Principal` in S3 bucket policies, see [the documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative suggestion:** Instead of giving each user their own bucket, you could grant each user access to a directory *within a shared bucket*.

This allows you to use an **IAM Policy Variable** that is much simpler to manage.

From [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This single policy on the bucket will let each user access their own directory. The name of the user will be automatically inserted into the policy. This means you only need to create one bucket with one policy.